# Field calculator formula converting DMS coordinate to decimal

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, fields-attributes, expression, degrees-minutes-seconds

I'm trying to convert DMS coordinate written as DD-MM-SS.SSS (ex. 17-42-35.244) in decimal, someone not human suggested me:

```
to_real(left("Field",2)) + 
to_real(mid("Field",4,2))/60 + 
to_real(right("Field",5))/3600
```

But QGIS says `Expression is invalid`.

If I consider only converting Degrees/Minutes/Seconds `to_real(left("Field",2))` without any other mathematical operation, I obtain some results.

What is wrong?

Comment: hi, thanks for suggestion. I know about to_decimal but in my qgis it does not exist. Thanks again

Comment: See updated answer. You seem to have a version older than 3.16. Time to update.

Answer (score 7):

Use  [`to_decimal()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#to-decimal) function, [introduced in QGIS 3.16](https://www.qgis.org/gl/site/forusers/visualchangelog316/index.html#add-to-decimal-function-to-convert-dms-to-dd):

```
to_decimal ("Field")
```

Example: if Field value is `'17-42-35.244'`, the output is `17.70979`

---

For QGIS versions older than 3.16, change your expression accordingly:

1. Function `mid()` does not exist. Use function [`substr()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#substr) instead.
2. In the last line, as parameter of the `right()` function, you must include 6, not 5 characters. The dot counts as a character, too. With 5, you just have `5.244` instead of `35.244` as input.

So the modified expression looks like:

```
to_real(left("Field",2)) + 
to_real(substring("Field",4,2))/60 + 
to_real(right("Field",6))/3600
```